# C program function to replace one word with another

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I am very confused to create a function which will  print a string and ask user to enter two numbers and then function will replace those number of words with one another.
I have added the image below as sample.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRoQl.jpg)

This is my homework, I have created other 3 functions, but don't really get this one. 
Could somebody please help me how can I convert the words into numbers and then replace those number of words with one another.

This is my program it can break the string into words but how can i replace position of words.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[100];
    char newString[10][10]; 
    int i,j,ctr;
       printf("\n\n Split string by space into words :\n");
       printf("---------------------------------------\n");    

    printf(" Input  a string : ");
    fgets(str1, sizeof str1, stdin);    

    j=0; ctr=0;
    for(i=0;i<=(strlen(str1));i++)
    {
        // if space or NULL found, assign NULL into newString[ctr]
        if(str1[i]==' '||str1[i]=='\0')
        {
            newString[ctr][j]='\0';
            ctr++;  //for next word
            j=0;    //for next word, init index to 0
        }
        else
        {
            newString[ctr][j]=str1[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n Strings or words after split by space are :\n");
    for(i=0;i < ctr;i++)
        printf(" %s\n",newString[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: suggest reading the sentence, word by word, into an array of words,  from there, the rest should be easy

Comment: That example is not very good. If taken literally that comma is going to be tricky to deal with.

Comment: I have added my current code now.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Would say the example is actually really good as it shows how to deal with commas.

Comment: where do you prompt for the indices of the words you'd like to swap?

Comment: @4386427 It depends on whether this is supposed to be a simple assignment or not. If punctuation is supposed to be special cased I'd expect more of a note to identify that, and this becomes a more complex assignment. If it's just a poorly chosen example and punctuation is not supposed to be special cased then it makes me sad if folks spend a lot of extra time trying to make that work if they are beginners. Maps well to the real world though, make sure you understand the requirements. :)

Comment: @Mr.Punjab Seems to me that you are doing pretty good so far (your code can't handle comma but you can add that later). So your next step is to construct a new string `str2` from the individual words you have in `newString`. While you do that you can simply swap the two words of interest. To build the new string the `strcat`function could be helpful

Comment: Thank you very much @ 4386427 
I am trying it now

Comment: @RetiredNinja true, handling of comma/punctuation/etc makes it more difficult. But to me swapping two words means: let comma/punctuation/etc be where they are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is code snippet what I tried in my local server based on your input in image.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 100
#define WORDLEN 20

int main() {
    int place_1, place_2, count = 0, i, k =0;
    char str[] = "Hi, welcome to C programming";
    char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*SIZE);
    if(!words){
        printf("malloc of words failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char *temp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*WORDLEN);
    if(!temp){
        printf("malloc of temp failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; count++){
        words[count] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*WORDLEN);
        if(!words[count]){
            printf("malloc of words[%d] failed!\n", count);
            exit(1);
        }
        sscanf(str+i, "%s", words[count]);
        i += 1+strlen(words[count]);
        printf("%d %s %d\n", count, words[count], i);
    }
    printf("Enter the word places to replace: ");
    if(scanf("%d %d", &place_1, &place_2) < 2){
        printf("scanf failed!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    temp = words[place_1 - 1];
    words[place_1 - 1] = words[place_2 - 1];
    words[place_2 - 1] = temp;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        sprintf(str+k, "%s ", words[i]);
        k += 1+strlen(words[i]);
    }
    printf("str: %s\n", str);
    free(temp);
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        free(words[i]);
    }
    free(words);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: My mistake. Now I added check for scanf & malloc.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are doing pretty good so far (your code can't handle comma but you can add that later). So let's assume that your `newString` actually contains the individual words.

So your next step is to construct a new string str2 from the individual words you have in `newString`. While you do that you can simply swap the two words of interest. To build the new string the `strcat` function could be helpful.

The code below is not fully correct but it may give you some ideas for getting on with your homework:

```
int lowest_index_to_swap = some_number
int highest_index_to_swap = some_higher_number

char str2[100] = "";

for (i=0; i<number_of_words_found; ++i)
{
     if (i == lowest_index_to_swap)
         strcat(str2, newString[highest_index_to_swap];
     else if (i == highest_index_to_swap)
         strcat(str2, newString[lowest_index_to_swap];
     else
         strcat(str2, newString[i];
     strcat(str2, " ";
}
```

Comment: `strcat` may work, but it grows woefully inefficient the more it is used.  Textbook "Shlemiel The Painter" algorithm. https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Performance of `strcat` is rarely of any interest in a program that reads user input from stdin